# Differences between Mac and Windows CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design, cross-browser, cross-platform

When I view this page on Chrome on Mac, the h1 text is on one line and scales correctly with the viewport on desktop screens. However, in Chrome on Windows machines, the h1 text breaks to two lines. I'm not sure what differences there are between OS/browser default styles, but I would like to always correctly scale the text size to be on one line for desktop (with the gold bar behind). I am using Foundation 6 for some responsive classes

**Mac Screenshot**
[View Mac Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ7Z4.png)

**Windows Screenshot**
[View Windows Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86ZP5.jpg)

**HTML**

```
<div id="video-header-container">
    <video loop muted autoplay>
        <source src="/img/home/tu-web-header.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="/img/home/tu-web-header.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    <video loop muted autoplay class="hide-for-medium">
        ## <source src="/img/home/tu-web-header.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="/img/home/tu-web-header-vertical.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    <div id="video-header-text">
        <h1 class="white-text position-relative margin-bottom-0">ON<br class="hide-for-large"> PURPOSE</h1>
        <div class="button-group stacked-for-medium margin-top-1 align-center">
            <a class="button" href="/visit">Schedule Your Visit</a>
            <a class="button" href="/accepted/deposit-housing">Make Your Deposit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #video-header-container {
        position: relative;
        height: calc(100vh - 70px);
    }
    @media (min-width: 1024px) {
         #video-header-container {
            height: calc(100vh - 165px);
         }
    }
    #video-header-container::before {
        content:"";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    }
    #video-header-container video {
        position: absolute;
        background: var(--tu-purple);
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
        -o-object-fit: cover;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
    
    #video-header-text {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    #video-header-text h1 {
        font-family: var(--font-sans);
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #video-header-text h1::before {
        content:'';
        background-color: var(--tu-gold);
        position: absolute;
        top: .45em;
        height: .5em;
        left: -5rem;
        right: -5rem;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    @media (max-width: 1023px) {
        #video-header-text h1 {
            font-size: 3.75rem;
        }
        #video-header-text h1::before {
            left: 3rem;
            right: 3rem;
        }
        #video-header-text h1::after {
            content:'';
            background-color: var(--tu-gold);
            position: absolute;
            bottom: .4em;
            height: .5em;
            left: -2rem;
            right: -2rem;
            z-index: -1;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1024px) {
        #video-header-text h1 {
            font-size: max(4.75rem, min(7.4vw, 7.5rem));
            font-size: clamp(4.75rem, 7.49vw, 7.5rem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is too many differences, you just need to use a css reset

Comment: Can you check in your browser's inspector to see what this class: hide-for-large actually does? I have just tried a display: none on a br element in Windows10 Edge and it works fine so the class must be doing something else.